# A question about the cardinality of $\theta$-closed hull of a set

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals, transfinite-induction

I have been reading a proof for the following proposition

> **Proposition:** Let $X$ be a Urysohn space. If $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $|[A]_\theta|\leq |A|^{\chi(X)}$

Here, $[A]_\theta$ denotes the $\theta-$closed hull of , which is the smallest $\theta-$closed set that contains $A$, and a $\theta-$closed set $C$ is such that $x\in C$ if and only if for every closed neighborhood  of $x$ intersects $C$. Also, $\chi$ denotes the character of the space. Well, there is a step in this proof that I do not quite understand, and here it is:

> Let $\kappa=|A|$, $A_0=A$ and by transfinite induction, let us define, for any $\alpha\in \kappa^+$ sets $A_\alpha$, in such a way that $A_\alpha=Cl_\theta (\bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha }A_\beta)$. It is easy to see that $$ \bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa^+} A_\alpha \subset [A]_\theta$$

And I do not really get this, I hope someone can explain why this is true, any comment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $Cl_\theta$ denote, is $Cl_\theta(A)$ different that $[A]_\theta$ and how? Is it a research paper you are reading, do you have a reference of a link? In the sentence "...closed hull of..." do you mean "...closed hull of $A$..."? Also definition of $\theta$-closed $C$, I cannot understand what is meant, if $x\in C$ then certainly every neighborhood of $C$ (closed or not) would intersect $C$ (at $x$). Could you improve the question please, so the definitions are more readily understood?

Comment: I recall that a subset $C$ of a topological space $X$ is called $\theta$-closed if each element $x\in X\setminus C$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}\cap C=\emptyset$.

Comment: I started to think more about your question. I assumed that for a subset $C$ of $X$, $Cl_\theta (C)$ is the same as $[C]_\theta$. But then I don’t understand why we need to consider the transfinite sequence $A_\alpha$, because we  already have $A_1=[A]_\theta$ and so $A_\alpha=A_1$ for all other $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Because $\theta-$closure is a non idempotent operator, i.e. $Cl_\theta(Cl_\theta (C))\neq Cl_\theta(C)$ in general. So, the $\theta- $closure of a set is not $\theta- $closed, in general.

Comment: Given a subset $C$ of a topological space $X$, the $\theta-$closure of $C$, denoted $Cl_\theta (C)$ is the set of all points $x$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, one has $\overline{U}\cap C\neq \emptyset$. And a set $A$ is called $\theta-$closed if $A=Cl_\theta (A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to see that $A_\alpha\subset [A]_\theta$ for each $\alpha\in\kappa^+$. We can easily see that by transfinite induction. Namely, we have $A_0\subset [A]_\theta$. Assume that $\alpha\in\kappa^+$ and 
we have $A_\beta\subset [A]_\theta$ for each $\beta \in \alpha$. Thus $\bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha }A_\beta\subset [A]_\theta$. Since the set $[A]_\theta$ is $\theta$-closed, $A_\alpha=Cl_\theta (\bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha }A_\beta)\subset [A]_\theta$.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Now,  I have one follow up question, and I hope you could give me a hand here. For any $x\in Cl_\theta (\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa^+}A_\alpha)$. Can I find some set $B$ such that $B\subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa^+}A_\alpha$ , $|B|\leq \kappa$ and $x\in Cl_\theta (B)$?  It seems like the answer is yes, but I cannot find a good argument to justify this

Comment: @VictorGustavoMay I guess there exists a counterexample, so I asked a specialist.